# Log and analyze web traffic passing through SSH SOCKS proxy

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I've got a cheap VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 that I sometimes proxy web traffic through via SSH when I don't trust the network I'm on. I'd like to have a closer look at some of that traffic on occasion. Is there an easy way to log extra information about HTTP requests passing through sshd?

There's nothing else running on the server, so logging all the OS's incoming and outgoing traffic is also a viable solution. I don't really need the actual data itself logged, mostly just the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a proxy server like nginx on your vps to accept request from local port 8080. Then setup your ssh tunnel to nginx port. Then check nginx access log whenever you like.

Comment: Does an HTTP proxy still support remote DNS lookups? I tried Googling and wasn't quite able to tell from what I saw. One of the places I frequently connect from messes with DNS traffic, so proxies don't work properly unless they tunnel DNS lookups as well.

Comment: If you are using firefox, you can give [this](http://ubuntu-tutorials.com/2008/06/18/tunnel-web-and-dns-traffic-over-ssh/) a try. It is quite old though. It show you how to configure firefox proxy for both http(s) and dns.